# ingreso de un nuevo campo incrementable

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla comprobantes en la cual tiene los campos
id,total, cliente_id
y lo que estoy tratando de hacer es crear un nuevo campo incrementable como el del id pero que se llame ticket, no importa el nombre la cosa es que se incremente automaticamente quedaria asi:

id, ticket, total, cliente_id

he probado campos tipos increments bigincrements autoincrement pero me devuelve puro error tambien intente usar el identity , pero no funciona aqui.

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->increments('ticket');
$table->decimal('total');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('cliente_id');
$table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes')->onDelete('cascade');
```

el error

> `ticket` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key

Answer (score 1):

La idea como originalmente la tienes no es correcta, hacer eso debería estar devolviendo un error como este:

> Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Lo cual te indica que el atributo `AUTO_INCREMENT` esta ligado inherentemente a la existencia de una columna que sea de tipo `PRIMARY KEY`, la cual será encargada de asignarle un nuevo valor a cada fila que exista en la tabla respectiva.

**ALTERNATIVA**

Pudieras crear a nivel de tu gestor de bases de datos un `TRIGGER` que lea el valor máximo asignado en la columna `tickets` y a partir de ese aumente el valor máximo existente de este modo:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER aumentaTicket
BEFORE INSERT ON tabla
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.columna  = (SELECT MAX(columna) + valorAincrementar FROM tabla);
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

- El `trigger` anterior se disparará antes de la inserción de una nueva fila en la tabla asignada
- Esteblece que obtenga el valor máximo existente en la columna seleccionada y a esa misma aumentarle sumando un valor específico

Comment: Eso tendria que agregar en migration? junto al campo que agregue?

Comment: No @SmithShenZySalazarYactayo el trigger se crea desde el motor de bases de datos

Comment: en mi migration no debo de crear ningun campo mas, solo desde mi phpmyadmin agrego lo que me dices.